# How to simulate sys.argv[1:] on web based python

Tags: python, file-upload

I have a Python program where the initiation script looks like this:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(sys.argv[1:])
```

To run this, I have to use Shell or Terminal like this:

```
myscript somefile.xml
```

The script accepts a file and then does all the rest of the work.
Now, I am trying to run this program on a web server.

SO I use a HTML Form to submit the file to this script.
In my Python script, I am doing like this:

```
....
elif req.form.has_key("filename"):
    item=req.form["filename"]
    if item.file:
        req.write("I GO HERE")
        myscript.main(item)
....
```

As you can see here, I am trying to send the file directly to the "main" function.
Is this the right way to do?

I dont get any script error, but the Python script is not producing the expected results.

Any help?
Thanks

Comment: What framework are you using? Or is it a CGI script? And what actually does happen?

Answer (score 1):

Write the uploaded file contents to a temporary file (using `tempfile.mkstemp()`) and pass the filename of the temporary file into `main()` wrapped in a list.

For example (untested):

```
import os
import tempfile    

fd, temp_filename = tempfile.mkstemp()
try:
    with os.fdopen(fd, "wb") as f:
        # Copy file data to temp file
        while True:
            chunk = item.file.read(100000)
            if not chunk: break
            f.write(chunk)

        # Call script's main() function
        myscript.main([temp_filename])
finally:
    os.remove(temp_filename)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply,
But I get an Syntax error here:
    with os.fdopen(fd, "wb") as f:

Comment: What version of Python?  You might need to add `from __future__ import with_statement` at the top of the file.

Comment: You need to use `f.flush()` after the copying loop to ensure, that internal IO buffers are flushed, and all data is really written to the file.  Moreover the code could be simplified by using `tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile` and `shutil.copyfileobj`.